# How to format to a string with minimum possible size

Tags: fortran, string-formatting

I have the following function:

```
function fname(proc, ct) result(filename)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: proc, ct
    character(len=100) :: filename

    write(filename,"(a,i9.9,a,i0,a)") "/step", ct, "-proc", proc, ".txt"
end function fname
```

In modern Fortran, is there an automatic way to have the resulting string to have the minimum possible size to fit all the formatted data? Notice the use of `i0` format makes the size of the resulting string variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not directly in the read statement. If you wrap the integer to string conversion into a function:

```
  function itoa(i) result(res)
    character(:),allocatable :: res
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    character(range(i)+2) :: tmp
    write(tmp,'(i0)') i
    res = trim(tmp)
  end function
```

you can then use allocatable deferred-length string

```
character(:), allocatable :: filename

filename = "/step" // itoa99(ct) // "-proc" // itoa(proc) // ".txt"
```

You can adjust the function, to take the integer format as a dummy argument instead of making more versions of it.

The other possibility is to have a large temporary string and trim it

```
character(100) :: tmp
character(:), allocatable :: filename

write(tmp,"(a,i9.9,a,i0,a)") "/step", ct, "-proc", proc, ".txt"

filename = trim(tmp)
```